# Resizable iPhone simulator doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

I recently wanted to use the brand new "Resizable iPhone simulator" to test my app in different screen resolution (with next iPhone it should change so...).

Anyway, each time I change the width and height values, nothing happens... And I can't enter values up to 768x1024.

Moreover, the spring board looks like iPad simulator more than iPhone. (And same with resizable iphone simulator).
I know it's still a beta so I expect bug, but here it seems totally useless and broken. So maybe it's just with me.

Anyone have same issues, ou get a functional resizable simulator ?

Comment: A comment would be appreciated on the downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's known bug which is documented in  [Xcode Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2014/xcode_6_beta_ie8g3n/xcode_6_beta__release_notes.pdf) and probably will be fixed in the next update.

Comment: Yup, precise answer, thank for the reference (but link seems broken, this one worked for me : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc6_release_notes/xc6_release_notes.html)

Answer (score 11):

I thought the resizable simulator in Xcode 6 beta wasn't working on mine either but I figured out what I was doing wrong and perhaps others might find it useful too.

The simulator works using 'point values' - e.g. the 4in resolution is 640x1136 but the simulator sees this as 320x568. So if you wanted to try out the rumoured 828x1472 resolution suggested by 9to5mac for example, you would put a width of 414 and height of 736 and then apply it to the simulator.

This works perfectly for me!

Comment: Excellent! Any idea what the `Regular`/`Compact` does?

Comment: Have a look at the User Guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator.html

Answer (score 0):

However it seems odd, and not like the hardware, that bounds still returns 1024x768 even though the frame size can be set smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Resize function not work as if iOS Simulator has resizable window:

> Important
>
> The iOS Simulator window resizes only a third-party app, not the Home screen or any app that ships with iOS.

— [iOS Simulator User Guide: Getting Started in iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH5-SW11)

You need to open your app to see changes.